# Bubble sort in Prolog language

Tags: prolog, bubble-sort

I must implement the bubble sort function (the sorting algorithm).

I have already implemented `bubblesort` and `swap`, a help function for `bubblesort`:

```
swap([X,Y|T1],[Y,X|T1]):-(Y<X,!).
swap([X|T1],[X|T2]):- swap(T1,T2).

bubblesort([],[]) :- !.
bubblesort(T1,T2) :- (bubblesort(swap(T1,T2),T2)).
```

I get an infinite loop. I must keep the signature of the function:

> bubblesort(T1,T2)

I'm stuck on this question for 2 hours. Does anyone have an idea how I can do that?

Comment: Ahh Prolog... __Bad__ memories :)

Comment: Ahh BubbleSort... Bad memories :)

Comment: Ahh, BubbleSort and Prolog... good memories ;)

Comment: If homework, please tag as such.

Comment: 10 years later ... aah prolog .... bad ^ ∞ memories

Answer (score 5):

Until there is no change in swap procedure, keep swapping. If there was no change in swap then you have sorted list.

```
bubblesort ( List, SortedList) :-
    swap ( List, List1 ), ! ,
    bubblesort ( List1, SortedList) .
bubblesort ( List, List).

swap ( [ X, Y | Rest ], [ Y, X | Rest ] ) :-
    X > Y, ! .
swap ( [ Z | Rest ], [ Z | Rest1 ] ) : -
    swap (Rest, Rest1 ).
```

Answer (score 2):

It almost hurts to write something so inefficient:

```
bubblesort(L, L1) :-
        (   bubble(L, L2)
        ->  bubblesort(L2, L1)
        ;   L = L1 ).

bubble([A, B|T], L) :-
        (   A > B
        ->  L = [B, A|T]
        ;   L = [A | L1],
            bubble([B|T], L1)).

:- bubblesort([2,4,2,3, 2, 6,6,3,1, 11, 2, 3, 1], Out).
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple [bubble sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) is made up of two main loops:

1. Traverse the list, 'swapping' each pair of elements if they are not 'in order' (inner loop).
2. Repeat (1) on the result until the list is completely sorted (outer loop).

The inner loop (1) can be expressed like this:

```
% performs a single pass of a bubble-sort on a list
do_bubble_sort([], []).
do_bubble_sort([X], [X]).
do_bubble_sort([X0,X1|Xs], [X0|Rem]) :-
    X0 =< X1, !,
    do_bubble_sort([X1|Xs], Rem).
do_bubble_sort([X0,X1|Xs], [X1|Rem]) :-
    do_bubble_sort([X0|Xs], Rem).
```

`do_bubble_sort/2` above takes a list, and recursively swaps consecutive elements along the list if they don't satisfy the `=<` test (3rd clause). This inner loop is then called by the outer loop predicate, `bubble_sort/2`, as shown below:

```
% repeatedly performs a bubble sort on a list until it is sorted
bubble_sort(L, SL) :-
    do_bubble_sort(L, L0),
    (sorted_order(L0) ->
        SL = L0
    ;   bubble_sort(L0, SL)
    ).
```

This predicate takes the input list and recursively applies `do_bubble_sort/2` until the predicate `sorted_order/1` succeeds on the result, i.e., if the list is eventually sorted. `sorted_order/1` can be defined like this:

```
% checks a list of things are in sorted (ascending) order
sorted_order([]).
sorted_order([_]) :- !.
sorted_order([X0,X1|R]) :-
    X0 =< X1,
    sorted_order([X1|R]).
```

This predicate takes a list and recursively checks that each pair of consecutive elements are in sorted order (by way of the `=<` test, just as we're using in `do_bubble_sort/2` - this is important, otherwise the algorithm mightn't terminate!)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by recursive querying. When querying `bubblesort(T1, T2)`,
it queries `bubblesort(swap(T1, T2), T2)`, then, by second clause of `bubblesort/2`,
`bubblesort(swap(swap(T1, T2), T2'), T2)` and `T2` is unified as `T2`, and then loop.
It never get the first result of `swap(T1, T2)` query.

Answer (score 0):

```
bubblesort ( List, SortedList) :-
    swap ( List, List1 ), ! ,
    bubblesort ( List1, SortedList) .
bubblesort ( List, List).
```

Answer (score 0):

```pl
bubbleSort(InputList,SortList):-swap(InputList,List),
                                 !,
                                 printList(List),
                                 bubbleSort(List,SortList).
bubbleSort(SortList,SortList).

swap([X,Y|T],[Y,X|T]):-X>Y.
swap([Z|T],[Z|T1]):-swap(T,T1).

printList([]):-nl.
printList([Head|List]):-write(Head),
                        write(' '),
                        printList(List).
```