# why does bubblesort([8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],L). return unsorted list?

Tags: prolog

```
bubblesort(inputList, SortList) :-
    swap(inputList, List), !,
    printlist(List),
    bubblesort(List, SortList).
bubblesort(SortList, SortList).

swap([X,Y |List], [Y,X|List]) :- X>Y.
swap([Z|List], [Z|List1]) :- swap(List,List1).

printlist([]) :- nl.
    printlist([Head|List]) :-
        write(Head), write(" "),
        printlist(List).
```

Comment: I want to get output in ascending order.Suppose, If I give bubblesort([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],L). as a query, I want to get L = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 as output!

Comment: Same question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753663/bubble-sort-in-prolog-language

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it like this:

```
bubblesort(SortList, NewSortList)
```

Since you are putting the same list as input and output, the `swap([X,Y |List], [Y,X|List])` rule will never match anything.

EDIT: Also, the swap predicate *might* be missing an end clause `swap([], []).`

EDIT 2: On second look, it isn't. The `swap` predicate will purposefully fail if it doesn't swap anything, so that `bubblesort` can continue to the `bubblesort(SortList, SortList).` clausule without getting stuck in an infinite recursion. I'm not sure if that is elegant or ugly code design.

Answer (score -1):

I got it, It will be InputList instead of inputList.